# Conditional assignment of default values in yang

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

I have two properties in a model:

- leaf protocol,
- leaf port.

I want to specify that:

- if protocol = 'ssh' then default port value is 22,
- if protocol = 'http' then default port value is 80,
- etc.

How do I express this in yang ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no conditional `default` values in YANG - you need two `default` statements for two `defaults` with different values, and a single `leaf` may only have one `default` substatement. You can work around this, however. Perhaps by using a `presence container` instead of your protocol `leaf`:

```
module conditional-default {
  namespace "http://example.com/conditional-default";
  prefix "excd";

  grouping common {
    leaf port {
      type int32;
    }
  }

  container config {

    container ssh {
      presence "If this container is present, ssh is configured.";
      uses common {
        refine port {
          default 22;
        }
      }
    }
    container http {
      presence "If this container is present, http is configured.";
      uses common {
        refine port {
          default 80;
        }
      }
    }

  }

}
```

From RFC6020, 7.5.5.:

> The "presence" statement assigns a meaning to the presence of a
>      container in the data tree.  It takes as an argument a string that
>      contains a textual description of what the node's presence means.

Comment: that is a possible work around, though, in my case, I cannot change the model structure.