# Yang Modeling Set a Field Based on Another Field

Tags: cisco, ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-netconf

I am writing a Yang model. Is there away to set a leaf (string or enumeration) with a value based on another field. So for example, I want to say if x then field a value is b, if z then field a value is c.

Edit: I am new to yang and still trying to learn it, if there are any other ideas or operators I can use to solve this issue please do not hesitate to share. :D Thank you very much.

Comment: You cannot do this in YANG - what you describe is a [conditional default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907872/conditional-assignment-of-default-values-in-yang/35916598#35916598). You may however constrain the valid value set of a node based on the value of another, like @Ariel suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `when` and `must` constructs: [YANG 1.1, Section 7.5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.5.3) says:

> The *must* statement, which is optional, takes as an argument a string that contains an XPath expression (see Section 6.4). It is used to formally declare a constraint on valid data. The constraintis enforced according to the rules in Section 8.

And [Section 7.5.4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.5.4.3) lays it out:

```
 container interface {
   leaf ifType {
     type enumeration {
       enum ethernet;
       enum atm;
     }
   }
   leaf ifMTU {
     type uint32;
   }
   must 'ifType != "ethernet" or ifMTU = 1500' {
     error-message "An Ethernet MTU must be 1500";
   }
   must 'ifType != "atm" or'
      + ' (ifMTU <= 17966 and ifMTU >= 64)' {
     error-message "An ATM MTU must be 64 .. 17966";
   }
 }
```

On `when`, [Section 7.21.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.21.5) reads,

> The *when* statement makes its parent data definition statement conditional. The node defined by the parent data definition statement is only valid when the condition specified by the *when* statement is satisfied. The statement's argument is an XPath expression (see Section 6.4), which is used to formally specify this condition.

ConfD provides a tutorial on [XPath in NETCONF and YANG](http://info.tail-f.com/xpath-netconf-yang); this examples comes out of it:

```
augment /system/login/user {
  when “class != ’wheel’”;
  leaf uid {
    type uint16 {
    range “1000 .. 30000”;
    }
  }
}
```