# Comparison based default value for a leaf in a same list in yang model

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-netconf

I would like to assign different default value to a leaf according to type of key the list entries take. as an example, although not correct:

```
typedef type-id {
    type enumeration {
      enum a{
        value 1;
      }
      enum b{
        value 2;
      }
      enum c{
        value 3;
      }
    }
}
list domain {
    key id;
    leaf id {
      type type-id;
    }
leaf my-leaf {
      when "../id = 'a'"{
        default 10;
      }
      when "../id = 'b'"{
        default 20;
      }
      when "../id = 'c'"{
        default 20;
      }
    }
}
```

So let say there are two entries for the list and the corresponding keys are 'a' and 'c'
When I walk through the model I would like to have values as

```
domain   id   my-leaf
```

---

```
         'a'    10
         'c'    30
```

Which expression is the best solution for this purpose? How can I model such a structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional assignment of default values in yang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907872/conditional-assignment-of-default-values-in-yang)

Comment: the solution provided not directly covering the question I think because I would like to make comparison with respect to the key value

Comment: It does not matter what the condition is (in your example a key comparison) - you are still trying to conditionally assign a default value, which cannot be done.